# Is it possible to implement the keyboard shortcuts on other parts of the site?

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

I like using the [keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/announcement-keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site), such as <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> for going to the previous/next post (or answer). However, these keyboard shortcuts do not work on **documentation** nor on the **search results** nor on the **jobs** section, while it would be nice to have them here as well.

For example:

- Use the <kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>U</kbd> shortcuts to browse search results
- Use the <kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>U</kbd> shortcuts to browse documentation tags
- Use the <kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>U</kbd> shortcuts to browse the documentation examples
- Use the <kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>U</kbd> shortcuts to browse jobs
- Use the <kbd>V</kbd> shortcut to vote for an example in a topic (Documentation)
- Use the <kbd>G</kbd> -> <kbd>D</kbd> shortcut to go to documentation
- Use the <kbd>E</kbd> to edit an example in a topic (Documentation)
- Use the <kbd>G</kbd> -> <kbd>J</kbd> shortcut to go to jobs

If it would be better to split this question up into multiple parts (such as a question about keyboard shortcuts for documentation and another one for the search results), please tell me.

Comment: I've been thinking about writting an user-script for exactly this, using Facebook/9gag's keyboard key bindings.

Comment: it would be a start to get the global shortcuts to work on documentation... like "**i**nbox", "**r**ecent achievements" or "**g**o to [...]". Those are completely unrelated to the site-content and don't work for unfathomable reasons

Comment: I'd like to see a keyboard shortcut for getting to the review queues. <kbd>G</kbd> -> <kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: This should probably be revised to remove everything related to discontinued features. I guess this is now really just a request to add shortcuts to search.